What are the three kinds of predicate argument?
I am looking up attribute nouns at the moment and I have come across the following statement.."It is true that an attributive noun can modify all three kinds of predicate argument." (source: www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)
This leads me to wonder what are the three kinds of predicate argument? I'm struggling to find this via google and my library books — can anyone please help?
thanks

The answer is given in the previous sentence but one in your link - "[A]ny noun can occur in three syntactic positions: as subject, direct object, and indirect object." All three must be a reference to this.

@KateBunting I assumed so too but thought I might be wrong so I came here

ThoughtCo says

... an argument is any expression or syntactic element in a sentence that serves to complete the meaning of the verb.

argument
In an attributive noun can modify all three kinds of predicate argument, the arguments are subject, direct object, and indirect object.
For example,
the clinic staff gave the flu patient a NAME OF DRUG injection
Each pair in bold consists of  a noun and its attributive noun.
